# The R-L fractional derivative interpretation

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, fractional-calculus

> The Riemann-Liouville fractional derivative of order $\alpha$ of a continuous function $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is defined as: 
>   $$D^{\alpha}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(n-\alpha)}(\frac{\partial }{\partial t})^n\int_{0}^{t}(t-s)^{n-\alpha -1}f(s)ds$$
>   where $n=[\alpha]+1$.

We know that the first derivative interpretes the function's slope, and the second interpretes its concavity. What is R-L fractional derivative intetrpretation?

Comment: For non-integer $\alpha$, this is a **non-local** operator.  That is, the value of $D^\alpha f$ at a point $x$ is not determined only by the values of $f$ near $x$, but also influenced by the values of $f$ far away.  So $D^{3/2}$ is not at all like $D^1$ or $D^2$ in that regard.

Comment: Great! so is there any interpretation of this derivative in the whole domain?